# Install WinForms application without admin rights

Tags: c#, windows-xp, installation, admin, rights

I develop a Windows Forms application using VS 2008. Application will be deployed in Corporate Environment: a network (VPN, LAN) is in several cities, many PC clients Windows XP; and there is a only Server Win2003, with several WCF Services, Windows Service, shared folders, and Database that use the WinForms app. Network is WORKGROUP, not domain.

The users in PC Clients has NOT admin rights. Only can install applications the only admin.

It is required **automatized&easy** way to install "desattended" the WinForms application for all users. I want get way to easy installations in PC Clients.

We don't want use ClickOnce. NOT use click once. Now, I have MSI (setup.exe) of WinForms App.
If if required another program, source code, scripting, etc, any sample code ??
any suggestions for my architecture network ??

Comment: it can be useful also: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms973920.aspx

Answer (score 2):

Use [XCOPY](http://help.infragistics.com/Help/NetAdvantage/WinForms/2010.2/CLR2.0/html/Win_Using_XCOPY_Deployment.html) Deployment for [more details](http://www.microsoft.com/resources/documentation/windows/xp/all/proddocs/en-us/xcopy.mspx?mfr=true).

Comment: I need install application for it appears in Control Panel -> Add/Remove Programs, and Start Menu -> Programs.

Comment: @alhambraeidos it is NOT impossible (i think) without rights (registry access). sorry. create just bat file, create shortcut "Remove MyApplication" and put it to the {c}:\Documents and Settings\{User}\Start Menu\Programs\{MyApplication}. Then user can remove your application by deleting all application files (remove-all.bat).

Comment: @alhambraeidos do the same with "start menu\program": create forlder, put shortcut...

Comment: any sample for create shortcut. Anyway, user  has not rights, can a user (not admin) create shortcut and copy files in c}:\Documents and Settings\{User}\Start Menu\Programs\{MyApplication} ?

Comment: @alhambraeidos 1) ShortCut: http://www.geekpedia.com/tutorial125_Create-shortcuts-with-a-.NET-application.html. 2) I think, yes, this is his or her directory {User}, right?

Answer (score 1):

Use [InnoSetup](https://jrsoftware.org/isinfo.php) and install the application to `%LOCALAPPDATA%\MyApp`, which is denoted as [`{localappdata}\MyApp`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=consts) in an ISS file.

Make sure your application uses Registry keys in HKEY_CURRENT_USER only. You can set these up using [`Root: HKLM`](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=registrysection)

Set [PrivilegesRequired](https://jrsoftware.org/ishelp/index.php?topic=setup_privilegesrequired) to `lowest`.