# Flutter compile for windows need visual studio installed

Tags: flutter, visual-studio, installation, portable-executable

when a run 'flutter doctor', the result is:

> [X] Visual Studio - develop for Windows
> X Visual Studio not installed; this is necessary for Windows development.
> Download at https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/downloads/.
> Please install the "Desktop development with C++" workload, including all of its default components

I need to install the Visual Studio on my windows. It must be easy if I have the root login on these windows (where i write right now), and I can ask by my superior to enable Visual Studio in this machine. But I don't want to install anything here.

What I really want to know is: There is a way to set up this dependency (Visual Studio) without any installation?
(just setting fome files and folders, like I do with flutter and dart)

Comment: If you dont want to build for windows , ignore this. Also you might have option to install on user(based on setting )

Comment: @YeasinSheikh can you teach how to install on my user (based on setting)?
I try but i'm not have sucess.

Comment: I think better you take help from administrator,  [SU Question](https://superuser.com/q/1322195/1641844) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3631455/10157127)